# android usb driver conflict with kernel mode driver

Tags: android, usb, driver

I have written an android usb driver(google api) to drive a printer with an android app.
if module usblp.ko is insmod, then my driver can not work correctly.

I know rmmod this module is a solution. but I want to do this automaticly!
Just like libusb has a api to "kick out the kernel driver" and use our driver.

Comment: can you provide the driver you have written?